i created sandwich attack python script using aave flashloan. is it correct? i created whole code
solidity contract function:
function executeOperation(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 premium,
    address initiator,
    bytes calldata params
) external override returns (bool) {
    require(asset == usdcAddress, "Invalid asset. Only USDC is supported.");

    // Decode parameters to get victim transaction data
    (address victimAddress, uint256 victimValue) = abi.decode(params, (address, uint256));

    // Logic to execute front-running and back-running trades goes here
    // Front-run: execute a buy/sell order with the borrowed funds

    // Back-run: execute a trade after the victim transaction

    // Calculate the total amount owed (loan + premium)
    uint256 amountOwed = amount + premium;

    // Approve the Pool contract to pull the owed amount
    usdc.approve(address(POOL), amountOwed);

    return true;
}

and python script function :
def trigger_flash_loan(victim_tx):
    try:
        # Estimate the effective transaction size based on the victim's transaction and liquidity conditions
        effective_transaction_value = max(web3.to_wei(10, 'ether'), victim_tx['value'] * 1.2)  # Dynamic sizing based on victim's transaction

        # Set loan amount and victim transaction details
        loan_amount = effective_transaction_value
        victim_address = victim_tx['to']
        victim_value = victim_tx['value']

        # Prepare transaction to call requestFlashLoan on the contract
        tx = flashloan_contract.functions.requestFlashLoan(loan_amount, victim_address, victim_value).build_transaction({
            'from': wallet_address,
            'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address),
            'gas': 500000,  # Set an appropriate gas limit
            'maxFeePerGas': web3.to_wei('100', 'gwei'),  # Adjust as needed
            'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.to_wei('2', 'gwei'),
            'chainId': 11155111  # Sepolia network
        })

        # Sign and send the transaction
        signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key)
        tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
        logging.info(f"Flash loan transaction sent: {web3.to_hex(tx_hash)}")

        # Wait for transaction receipt
        receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
        if receipt.status == 1:
            logging.info("Flash loan executed successfully.")
        else:
            logging.error("Flash loan execution failed.")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error triggering flash loan: {e}")


It's still quite far off. You can't request a flash loan from a script since you need to pay in the contract call back, which is where you put the logic handling the funds you borrow. Sandwiches aren't like arbitrage though, you are going to need to hold the tokens across transactions in order to front and back run. You'll either need to use an endpoint that accepts bundles, build blocks, or really fine tune gas parameters to order the 3 transactions.

@Maka so we cannot request flashloan to execute sandwich attack?

You cannot, a flash loan needs to be paid in the callback which happens instantly. Sandwiches require an investment and carry increased risk from holding an asset across the transactions. It's a little more advanced, so maybe better to start with liquidation or arbitrage bots, both can use flash loans.
